# How to define a indicator for the data from each file in the indirect load in Informatica

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, workflow-manager-1.x

I'm working on a Informatica load where i'm loading 3 files into the table using the Indirect load session property. Now i have to created a new indicator field in the target table which need to be populated with the file names where i have imported from.

I have 3 files: A.csv, B.csv and C.csv

I have created a new field in the target table called 'Feed' which need to be populated as shown below

```
Feed
A.csv
B.csv
C.csv
```

How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://network.informatica.com/thread/31217 comment by Pravneesh which shows how to configure the source to add a currently processed filename column